# httpclient API for setHttpRequestRetryHandler

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

The HTTP commons client 4.12 [tutorial section on exception handling](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e292) clearly shows that one should be able to set a request retry handler by doing the following...

`httpclient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(myRetryHandler);`

in eclipse I tried that and it reports HttpClient has no such method. It suggests i cast the client to `AbstractHttpClient` then call .`setHttpRequestRetryHandler` like so:

`((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).setHttpRequestRetryHandler(myRetryHandler);`

then my code works, but this discrepancy between documentation and API makes me wonder if I'm doing something I shouldn't.

Is the documentation wrong or is it me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're totally correct. The documentation uses a concrete `DefaultHttpClient` (which is a subclass of `AbstractHttpClient` and so has the `setHttpRequestRetryHandler()` method.

As you are doing the right thing and programming to the `HttpClient` interface (which sadly doesn't expose that method), you have to do that nasty cast.

It looks like the Apache team have decided to keep the `HttpClient` interface super-clean, at the expense of client code :-(

Comment: The underlying assumption is that one uses a concrete class such as `DefaultHttpClient` to fully initialize the client and then uses the `HttpClient` interface reference in the application code. The super-clean `HttpClient` interface makes it easier to provide additional functionality through interface decoration. HttpClient 4.2 ships with several such decorators: for transparent content decoding, response caching, and automatic recovery.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to use HttpClient in this case is to use [AutoRetryHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AutoRetryHttpClient.html), which accepts a [DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy.html). One possible reason, why this is often overlooked is that AutoRetryHttpClient implements HttpClient interface instead of extending AbstractHttpClient. No need for casting in this case.

```
DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy retryStrategy = new DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(5, 50);
AutoRetryHttpClient          httpClient = new AutoRetryHttpClient(retryStrategy);
```

Comment: Thx! The second parameter is the retry interval. Guess it is in milli secs. Wish people name their time params with units, like `retryIntervalMillis` instead of simply `retryInterval`.

Comment: This answer is misleading. In Apache HC `ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy` and `HttpRequestRetryHandler` are completely two different things. One is used for retrying on receiving bad http response code (which indicates the request was delivered successfully at least); however the latter is to retry on exceptions, which could be broken pipe, connection reset by peer and etc.